# Load URLs to python through text file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want my for loop to take URLs one by one and hit and do some operations like, [clicking button and extracting text] first time when the URL is hit it needs uname, pwd and login from next time onwards no need credentials, it can directly just click button and extract URL.

Operational code : for clicking and extracting is working fine. only for loop has some issue

```
 def lookup(driver,uname,pwd):
    with open("A.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            url = line.strip()
            print("Getting %s" % url)
            driver.get(url)
            box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "j_username")))
            box.send_keys(uname)
            box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "j_password")))
            box.send_keys(pwd)
            button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login")))
            button.click()
            button = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fetchCandidateChanges_0")))
            button.click()
            driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
            time.sleep(15)
            labels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[@class="pagebanner"]')
            for label in labels:
                print (label.text)
```

Comment: Never used selenium but I suppose you need to get rid of the double quotes in `driver.get("content")`. It should be `driver.get(content)`. And you missed a loop here as well, if you want to read all the URLs.

Comment: @NitheeshAS Thanks Bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each line contains an URL:

```
def lookup(driver,uname,pwd):
    with open("A.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            url = line.strip()  # to remove the trailing \n
            print("Getting %s" % url)
            driver.get(url)
```

A `for` loop will iterate on the lines of the file.

Comment: You forgot the indentation of the for loop ^^

Comment: Yes, and stripping the trailing \n :/, I just noticed, thanks!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for the answer.. when tried with 3 URLs. driver.get(url) is loading the 3rd URL alone

Comment: If all of your URLs are valid, maybe there's something going wrong in another part of your code...

Answer (score 1):

1. `read()` reads the whole file as a single string, so `content` is the string `"url1\nurl2\url3"` etc
2. `driver.get("content")` You assign the content of the file to `content` but passing the string `"content"` to `get`. `content` and `"content"` are *not* the same thing.

Instead, you should read the file line by line and pass each url to `get`:

```
def lookup(driver, uname, pwd):
    with open("A.txt") as f:
        urls = f.readlines()
    for url in urls:
        print(url)
        driver.get(url)
```

or

```
def lookup(driver, uname, pwd):
    with open("A.txt") as f:
        for url in f:
            print(url)
            driver.get(url)
```

I usually tend to go with the first style as it doesn't keep the file opened unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace. am able to read file now, but I wants to read the URLs one by one and for each URL I need to perform set of operations.. when tried with 3 URLs. driver.get(url) is loading the 3rd URL alone. please help

Comment: Print an example of your textfile. If the urls arent separated by newlines then they will get mangleled when you iterate over them.

Comment: sample file : https://ops.stg2.ddd.com/listPullGroup.html?name=Test_LP&startDate=01-11-2016&endDate=31-11-2016&actedOn=false
https://ops.stg2.ddd.com/listPullGroup.html?name=24599_TKT_CS_META&startDate=01-11-2016&endDate=31-11-2016&actedOn=false
https://ops.stg2.ddd.com/listPullGroup.html?name=24634_TKT_CS_IMAGE&startDate=01-11-2016&endDate=31-11-2016&actedOn=false

Comment: https://ops.stg2.ddd.com/listPullGroup.html?name=Test_LP&startDate=01-11-2016&endDate=31-11-2016&actedOn=false
https://ops.stg2.ddd.com/listPullGroup.html?name=24599_TKT_CS_META&startDate=01-11-2016&endDate=31-11-2016&actedOn=false
https://ops.stg2.ddd.com/listPullGroup.html?name=24634_TKT_CS_IMAGE&startDate=01-11-2016&endDate=31-11-2016&actedOn=false

Comment: This comments editor strips out newlines. That's why I said "print" not paste :D. If you are using DeepSpace's suggested implementation, note that the get actions might be executed in very fast succession in your browser and you won't be able to physically see the page change. Add a delay or some selenium logging to see which URLs are opened.

Comment: Wait, are you expecting the labels list to update with all labels from all users? Cause if you do, thats not what the code does. It will print all text inside labels for each of the XPATH elements for each user. and the last value of labels will be the list of elements found on the last URL.

Comment: @BoboDarph Dude ! Xpath part is working as expected. the problem here is with the for loop.. My problem stmt is  : For first time in for loop, allow Uname, pwd, and login click, from next time directly click this [fetchCandidateChanges_0] cos UI will not ask for credentials everytime. Reason : all URLs are from same domain